# Parsing integer with decimal points

Tags: java

How to parse the below value as int.Do we have any specific classes in java.math?

```
       String string="500.0000000";
```

I tried like below ,it is throwing Number Format exception.

```
       int x=Integer.parseInt(string).
```

Regards,

Raj

Comment: Parse it as double and then round to an int?

Comment: integer can't hold decimal values, use Double instead

Comment: What Henry said.  But you also have to define what you want to do if the string (e.g. the user input) contains 500.1000 or something.  Do you want to round it, or do you want to reject it and make the user enter something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it in a single line by

```
String string="500.0000000";
int x = Double.valueOf(string).intValue();
System.out.println(x);
```

**OR**

```
int x = (int)Double.parseDouble(str);
```

you will get Output as

```
500
```

here `Double.valueOf(string)` parse string to double value

and

that parsed double value converted into int type using `.intValue();`

Comment: Note that `Double.valueOf` creates a new `Double` object. `parseDouble()` is better option.

Comment: @RohitJain ThanQ Rohit, i have modified my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Parse it as a double and convert it to an integer then:

```
String s = "500.0000000";
double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
int i = (int) d;
```

The way Java cast an double to a int is that it removes the decimal piece.

Comment: Or even `Double.valueOf(string).intValue();`

Answer (score 0):

A decimal means it's not an integer. Try parsing it as a float or double:

```
float f = Float.parseFloat(string);
```

And if you need it as an int, you can try casting it:

```
int x = (int)f;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is, that you try to parse a double value into an int. But if you need this to work in other countries, too, this is what you need:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance( Locale.GERMANY );
System.out.println( nf.parse( "100.0000000" ) ); // ->  1000000000

nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance( Locale.US );
System.out.println( nf.parse( "100.0000000" ) ); // -> 100
```